# Scraping No Link

Tags: django, web-scraping

I'm learning xpath & web scraping using django-dynamic-scraper aka DSS (django+scrapy) and try to retrieve data from a website with following code:

```
<tr valign="top">
    <td align="center" valign="top">
        <p><img src="someimage.jpg"></p>
    </td>
    <td>
    &nbsp;
    </td>
    <td>
        <div align="left">
            <span class="style1">
                <strong>Title1</strong>
            </span>
            <span class="style2">Title2:</span>ContentA<br />
            <span class="style2">Title3:</span>ContentB<br />
            <span class="style2">Title4:</span>ContentC<br />
        </div>
    </td>
</tr>
```

My questions:

- What's the xpath for `an URL object of DSS` if there's no link at that code?
- What's the xpath to retrieve image file if there's no class for first `<td>`?
- How to retrieve data for *each* data from ContentA, ContentB, & ContentC if the span's class is `same`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> What's the xpath for an URL object of DSS if there's no link at that code?

Can't get the question, could you please explain?

> What's the xpath to retrieve image file if there's no class for first ?

`//tr[1]/td[1]//img/@src`

> How to retrieve data for each data from ContentA, ContentB, & ContentC
>   if the span's class is same?

`//text()[preceding-sibling::span[@class="style2"]]`